# Keyboard settings and Hyper-V for a user created account

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2022, keyboard

I have encountered a strange situation when I use Hyper-V with an account that I created myself (that is part of the Administrators group).

Specifically, I want to be able to send Function key presses (i.e. F1, F2, F3, etc.) to my host box rather than the virtual machine. I have been able to achieve this by configuring my Hyper-V server to send Windows Key combinations to the Physical Computer (Hyper-V server -> User settings -> Keyboard) while logged in with the default Administrator user.

However, my function keys are not sent to the host if I log in as a user that I create, even if I make that user part of the Administrators group; those keystrokes are sent to the VM. I tried other things like adding that user to the "Hyper-V Administrators group" but that didn't work.

I have observed other strange behavior with the default Administrator account versus a user created account that is part of the Administrators group when it comes to changing the timezone- basically, that user has to be explicitly granted that right through Local Security Policy settings.

My hunch is this keyboard issue has a similarly obscure setting somewhere, but I'm not sure where to look.